# Why File is not uploading in specified upload path in models in Django, It is uploading in expected directory when uploaded from the admin

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to upload some files using normal CRUD operation in Django. The files are uploading at the media directory of the project while normally uploaded and when I try to upload the files from the admin area it is uploading in the expected directory ie. inside media/cv.

I've defined the models for the database and also defined the media root and added it into the urlpatterns variable too. All seems okay and works just fine when I try to upload the file from admin view but when I try to upload file normally the file is uploaded directly in the media directory, not in media/cv.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py in project level

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls'))
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Student(models.Model):
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='cv')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('student/create', views.insert_student, 
        name='create_student'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import Student

def insert_student(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cv = request.FILES['cv']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(base_url='')
        cvname = fs.save(cv.name, cv)
        cv = fs.url(cvname)
        stud = Student(cv=cv)
        stud.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

student_form.html

```
 <form method="post" action="{% url 'create_student' %}" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input name="cv" type="file" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

I expected the files to be uploaded inside  media/cv when normally uploaded from the form but the file is uploading in the media directoy. When I added the student from admin login the file is uploading in the media/cv directory.

Comment: you can skip the whole manual file saving and just do `stud = Student(cv=request.FILES['cv']); stud.save()`. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you're not letting your model save the file, you're saving it explicitly using `FileSystemStorage`. Nowhere in that code do you set the directory to be `cv`.

Since you're using a model with a `FileField`, you only need to do this to save your file:

```
stud = Student(cv=request.FILES['cv'])
stud.save()
```

This will ensure your file is saved within the `cv` directory inside your `media` folder. I would add a check before doing that though, because `request.FILES['cv']` can raise a `KeyError` exception if that isn't posted. Also you're not even checking the content of the file before saving. That's a big security loophole as anyone can upload anything this way, including files containing malware/viruses.

Comment: this is the answer i wanted. Thank you